# A function to calculate estimated duration

Tags: excel, excel-formula, finance, quantitative-finance

I would like to know if there is an existing function in Excel (e.g., in finance) to undertake the following task.

Imagine we have planned the sales of a product for 2013 as C5:G6. And we have stock in J10. We want to calculate the estimated number of months the stock can support the sales. For instance, given the stock is `360`, it has enough quantity for `100` in January and `200` in February, and there will be `60` left, which will be consumed in `60/300` months, thus the expected return value is `2,2` months.

[image]

I have written a long formula in Excel to do so:

```
= LET(
    ps;
    C6:G6;
    sq;
    J10;
    cumuls;
    SCAN(0; ps; LAMBDA(a; b; a + b));
    m;
    REDUCE(
      0;
      cumuls;
      LAMBDA(acc; value; IF(value <= sq; acc + 1; acc)));
    IFS(
      m = 0;
      sq / INDEX(ps; 1; 1);
      m >= COLUMNS(ps);
      m;
      TRUE;
      (sq - INDEX(cumuls; 1; m)) / INDEX(ps; 1; m + 1) + m))
```

However, I'm wondering if there is any existing function in Excel for this purpose.

Comment: It would help to post data as data, so we don't need to retype everything to test.

Comment: how to "post data as data"?

Comment: You could make use of https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but this formula would spill the result in one go:

```
=LET(months,TRANSPOSE(C6:G6),
     stock,J6:J11,
     cml,SCAN(0,months,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
     mx,XMATCH(stock,cml,1),
(stock-INDEX(cml,mx))/INDEX(months,mx)+mx)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But my question is about whether there is an existing function for this purpose.

Comment: No, this is not achievable without combining functions.